# Capture the value of a variable that changes through time

Tags: java, variables

Let's say I have a variable x that changes while the code runs. I want to assign the actual value of x to another variable y. If i just assign it as always (`int y = x`) the value of y changes through time as well.
I also want to be able to refresh the value of y whenever I want.

```
int y = x; //let's assume this actually works
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("later");
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
y = x;
System.out.println("refresh");
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
```

That would be the ideal output.

```
y=20 x=20
later
y=20 x=423
refresh
y=423 x=423
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for. Maybe the Observer Pattern?

Comment: `y = x` captures it, so if you do that only once, at the point in time where `x` has the value you want to capture, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method as follows:

```
int storePrev(int x) {
     return x;
}
```

Just call this method before you change the value of x. This will duplicate x without assigning.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written actually works (at least for primitive). Just try to run the following :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int x = 20;
    int y = x; //let's just see if it actually works
    System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    x += 403;
    System.out.println("later");
    System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
    y = x;
    System.out.println("refresh");
    System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
}
```

This printed me :

```
y=20 x=20
later
y=20 x=423
refresh
y=423 x=423
```

Isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm trying to compare the two variable. Somewhere in my code there's this :
    `if(y==x) {
    //do something
    }`
And it never enters the if, I know it's because y gets the value of x to check the condition, it's like writing `if(x==x)`. I'm trying to just duplicate the value of x to y.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a record of all the values that are assigned to y then you can simply create an Array.
Example:

```
i=0;
i++; 
int y[i] = x; 
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);// here you can simply print the y[i] you want
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("later");
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);// here you can simply print the y[i] you want
i++
y[i] = x;
System.out.println("refresh"); 
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);// here you can simply print the y[i] you want
```

If you only want to keep the previous x then you simply change the value of x after the y=x statement.Example:

```
int x=20; 
int y = x; // y becomes 20
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
Thread.sleep(2000); //suppose x becomes 423
System.out.println("later"); 
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
y = x; // y also becomes 423
System.out.println("refresh");
System.out.println("y="+y+" x="+x);
```